# What is the purpose of the arrowhead in angle arc?

Tags: geometry

What is the purpose of the arrowhead in the arcs of angles? Specifically, please see the two plot-images I've uploaded. What is the difference of placing the arrowhead in the beginning or at the end of the arc?

[image: counterclockwise_angle]

[image: clockwise_angle]

---

Ok, lets ignore the blue angle and arc. I am interested in the red only. What difference does it make if the arrowhead is on the $0$ degrees ray or on the $30$ degrees ray?

Also, does the arc necessary imply that the angle is changing or can an arc be used for a static angle that does not change ?

Comment: I don't see the arrowhead having a purpose in those illustrations. In some contexts it might look nice or provide some intuition about which side is being "lifted" to construct the angle -- especially if you're looking at an angle changing, like when you construct the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

An angle is between two half lines. You need to indicate which is the origin and which is the destination, to avoid a sign ambiguity.

In the context of complex arguments, you may consider that the origin is implicitly the $x$ axis.

Your second figure is wrong. $\phi$ being a negative angle, $\phi-90°$ must extend past the negative $y$ axis.